# Slow PostgreSQL Query for Mins and Maxs within equal intervals in a time period

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a system with lots of devices that take measurements. These measurements are stored in table "sample_data".
There could be 10M measurements in a single year per device. Most of the time the user is only interested in 100 min max pairs within equal interval for a certain period, for example in last 24 hours or in last 53 weeks. To get these 100 mins and maxs the period is divided into 100 equal intervals. From each interval min and max is extracted. Would you recommend the most efficient approach to query the data? So far I have tried the following query:

```
WITH periods AS (
  SELECT time.start AS st, time.start + (interval '1 year' / 100) AS en
  FROM generate_series(now() - interval '1 year', now(), interval '1 year' / 100) AS time(start)
)
SELECT s.* FROM sample_data s
  JOIN periods ON s.time BETWEEN periods.st AND periods.en 
  JOIN devices d ON d.customer_id = 23
  WHERE
    s.id = (SELECT id FROM sample_data WHERE device_id = d.id and time BETWEEN periods.st AND periods.en ORDER BY sample ASC LIMIT 1) OR
    s.id = (SELECT id FROM sample_data WHERE device_id = d.id and time BETWEEN periods.st     AND periods.en ORDER BY sample DESC LIMIT 1)
```

This query took about 4 sec. It is not very suitable because sample_data table can contain up to 10M rows per device.
I see it runs not in very optimized way but have no idea why. I thought I had indexed all the critical fields used in this query.

Would you recommend me a way to fetch such statistics more faster?

Table "devices":

```
       Column       |            Type             |                      Modifiers                       
--------------------+-----------------------------+------------------------------------------------------
 id                 | integer                     | not null default nextval('devices_id_seq'::regclass)
 customer_id        | integer                     | 

    <Other fields skipped as they are not involved into the query>
Indexes:
"devices_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
"index_devices_on_iccid" UNIQUE, btree (iccid)
```

It has 12 devices and only 4 devices for customer_id = 23 which is specified in the query.

Table "sample_data":

```
     Column     |            Type             |                        Modifiers                         
----------------+-----------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------
id             | integer                     | not null default nextval('sample_data_id_seq'::regclass)
sample         | numeric                     | not null
time           | timestamp without time zone | not null
device_id      | integer                     | not null
customer_id    | integer                     | not null
Indexes:
"sample_data_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
"sample_data_device_id_time_sample_idx" btree (device_id, "time", sample)
```

It has about 1.7M rows. About 720K rows for every device of 4 which are belong to the customer_id = 23.
The table is filled by test data now.

"select version()" result:

```
PostgreSQL 9.3.5 on x86_64-apple-darwin13.3.0, compiled by Apple LLVM version 5.0 (clang-500.2.79) (based on LLVM 3.3svn), 64-bit
```

track_io_timing set to "on"

EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) results here:
  http://explain.depesz.com/s/kA12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that the drivers of performance are the queries in the `where` clause.  Let's look at one of these:

```
WHERE s.id = (SELECT sd.id
              FROM sample_data sd
              WHERE sd.device_id = d.id and
                    sd.time BETWEEN periods.st AND periods.en
              ORDER BY sd.sample ASC
              LIMIT 1
             )
```

You have an index on `sample_data(devide_id, time, sample)`, and you want the database engine to use this index.  Unfortunately, it can take full advantage of the index only for the `where` clause.  Because of the `between`, it probably won't use the index for the `order by`.

Is it possible to write the `order by` using `time`?

```
WHERE s.id = (SELECT id
              FROM sample_data
              WHERE device_id = d.id and
                    time BETWEEN periods.st AND periods.en
              ORDER BY time ASC
              LIMIT 1
             )
```

Comment: Got it, thanks. Unfortunately I can not. "sample" field is for measured values and I use ordering by it to get min and max points for a period.

Comment: @eug.nikolaev . . . Well, that does demonstrate the Postgres will do the right thing with indexes.

Comment: So is it possible to get that kind of data by query? If not - looks like I will have to prepare max mins on data insert..

Comment: Gordon Linoff, thanks for your explanations! Decided not to use sorting there. It will work (for now).